# Displaying the SMSC address which was used for sending an SMS to my phone in Android

Tags: android, service, sms, center, inbound

In Android, is it possible to somehow display the SMSC address which was used for sending a given SMS to my phone? I'd like to write an app which lets me pick one of my stored SMS and then displays this SMSC address. Preferably this would happen as an extension to the "message details" dialogue box which can be invoked by long pressing an SMS.

Note: I do not mean the SMSC address of my phone's operator which is used for sending SMS from my phone to other phones.

I tried to find something in the now deprecated SMS content provider but either I did not look hard enough, or it's simply not stored after receiving the SMS.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You won't be able to add this functionality to your existing SMS app; you'd have to write your own app that lists your SMS and extracts this info.